# Perform a calculation without bitwise operator

Tags: c, algorithm

I would like to perform this calculation wihout the bitwise operator.

```
unsigned result = (1u << 5);
```

The result will be 32. I know that's converting the binary `1` to `100000` but I would like to perform the same thing *without* bitwise operations.

Comment: `unsigned result = 1; for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) result *= 2;`

Comment: Calculus? Where? Shouldn't it be calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know that 2<sup>5</sup> is 32, you could just use:

```
unsigned int result = 1u * 32u; // or just 32u if it's always '1u *'.
```

Otherwise, if you just want to use the bitshift value, there are two ways. The first is a loop:

```
unsigned result = 1u;
for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; result *= 2u, i++);
```

or a non-loop version:

```
static unsigned int shft[] = {1u, 2u, 4u, 8u, 16u, 32u, ... };
unsigned int result = 1u * shft[5]; // or just shft[5] if it's always '1u *'.
```